# Super Mario Run parent/child DLC sharing?

Tags: nintendo-network-id, super-mario-run

I just bought the level pack in Super Mario Run on iPad for my kid. He's logged on to his own Nintendo Network Id, which is a child account registered under my own NNID.
I'd like to play this game myself as well (preferably on my phone, as soon as it comes out on Android) using my own NNID. Will I have to buy the game again under my own Nintendo Network Id?

I've seen other questions about sharing DLC between devices but they either assume you're using the same NNID or the same Apple id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I had to buy the game twice. Each NNID holds its own DLC, I was not able to reuse this even though the accounts are linked together.

This is sort of what I expected, but not what I had hoped :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe AppleID matters in this case.  If you sign in using your child's NintendoID, you should be able to use the DLC.  I don't know if playing at the same time is possible (anecdotally, given comments online, it seems like it is allowed) and you would share progress for which levels have been unlocked, Toad Rally, etc.

While it is the same AppleID, I have it installed on both my phone and iPad and can switch back and forth without issue.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't answer my question. I'm asking if the DLC is shared between our NNID accounts because I registered him as a child account. I'll try to improve the question so that this is more explicit.